# Confusion about non-significant interaction

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data, interaction

I'm running a linear model with two binary independent variables, Group (1 and 2) and Condition (A and B). Both have p-values < 0.05. Looking at plots of my results, it looks like there should be an interaction, but adding an interaction term gives a p-value > 0.05. The two main effects are also no longer significant. I'm wondering if it is because the interaction term is correlated too highly with the main effects.

Here is a plot showing means and confidence intervals for each category:
[image]

I don't understand why the interaction is not significant. Condition clearly has little to no effect on Group 1, so I'm confused about how to interpret my results. I can't say from looking at the data that Condition has an effect across both Groups, but - as the interaction is not significant - I feel like the results of the model don't permit me to talk about the effect of Condition only being relevant for Group 2.

Comment: If you look at the values of the means, there appears to be an interaction effect. But pay attention to the confidence intervals you have plotted. The interval for 2B overlaps those for 2A and 1B.  There is too much variability in the measurements, or too few samples, for the model to reject the hypothesis that there is no interaction effect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It doesn't quite overlap with 2A but I can see that it overlaps with 1B. So I guess the main effects are significant by themselves because 2B is significantly different from 1A and 2A? And, because of this, it concludes that both Group and Condition have an effect, even though Condition has no discernable effect on Group 1?